# Php - isset() condition doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

I am a newbie to PHP. & My PHP Code doesn't work, I want to update some date using MySQL but it seems that first IF condition is 'false' i don't why, I am using PHP 7 & XAMP as a local host, Dreamweaver as an IDE & this is my code:

```
if(isset($_POST["btn_edit"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    if(!empty($_FILES["img"]["name"]))
    {
        $img = $_FILES["img"]["name"];
        $img_temp = $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
        if(move_uploaded_file($img_temp, "assets/images/".$img))
        {
            $query = mysqli_query($Connection, "UPDATE entry_data SET names='$name',emails='$name',passwords='$password',images='$img' WHERE id='$ID'");
            if($query)
            {
                $result = header("Location:index.php");
            }
            else
            {
                echo mysql_error();
            }   
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($Connection, "UPDATE entry_data SET names='$name',emails='$name',passwords='$password',images='$img' WHERE id='$ID'");
        if($query)
        {
            echo "<h5>Updated</h5>";
        }
    }
}
```

it showing me nothing just refresh the page & this is HTML CODE:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" />
<input name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" />
<input name="password" value="<?php echo $password ?>" />
<img width="50" height="50" src="<?php echo 'assets/images/'.$row[4] ?>" />
<input name="img" type="file" class="text-info" required="required" />
<br/>
<input name"btn_edit" type="submit" />
<?php if(isset($_POST["btn_edit"])) echo $result ?>
```

Comment: It's simply because $_POST["btn_edit"] coming as empty. Check it like echo $_POST["btn_edit"]; die; before if condition.

Comment: need to post your form, basic debugging = echo variables

Comment: check that your `submit button` has `name="btn_edit"`

Comment: but why I set btn_edit to submit button

Comment: What is `btn_edit`? Please post the code where the form is and we will solve it for you in an instant . It's hard this way, because the `isset` from above should work fine.

Comment: try using print_r($_POST) to check the output code.

Comment: '<input name"btn_edit" type="submit" />' this is edit button

Comment: you are missing a `=` in `name="btn_edit"`

Comment: Thank u guys, u took ur time to showing my silly mistake.

Comment: You can also use below condition for checking either page have post data or not:
if(!empty($_POST)){ 

 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have syntax issue in your button HTML.

This:-

```
<input name"btn_edit" type="submit" />
```

Need to be:-

```
<input name="btn_edit" type="submit" /><!-- = is missing in name -->
```

Comment: @RoxasZohbi  we all learn from mistakes.So don't worry. Glad to help you :):)